# Upload Zip File and Extract the Zip

Tags: php, file-upload, zip, extract

I have a form (HTML) which submits a file to a PHP script which renames the file to ZIP, stores it in a folder (random name) and then extracts that file.

The file gets uploaded.
The folder is created correctly.
The file gets renamed correctly.

The extraction of the zip fails.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">

Select file 
<input name="ufile" type="file" id="ufile" size="50" />

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />

 </form>
```

Here is the PHP script - up.php

```
$file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'];
$random_digit=rand(0000,9999);
$new_file_name=$random_digit.".zip";
mkdir($random_digit, 0777, true);

$path= $random_digit.'/'.$new_file_name;
if($ufile !=none)
 {
    if(copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path))
 {
 echo "The upload is successful<BR/>"; 
 echo "File Renamed to: ".$new_file_name." for processing.<BR/>"; 
 echo "File Size :".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['size']."<BR/>"; 
 echo "<strong><a style='color:#6A8DBC; text-decoration:none' href='".$link_address."'>Proceed to the next phase of the importation of data to the system</a></strong></br>";
  }
 else
  {
   echo "Error";
   }
 }

  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open($new_file_name);
  if ($res === TRUE) {
     $zip->extractTo($random_digit.'/');
     $zip->close();
     echo 'extraction successful';
     } else {
     echo 'extraction error';
     }
```

Is it the mode of the folder which prevents extraction? As far as I can see, there is no syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$res = $zip->open($path)
```

As you have moved the file to `$path` you then need to operate on the file at `$path`

Comment: You are correct. I didn't include the right path. Thanks. This works.

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php 

function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
       if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
       if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
       else unlink("$dir/$file");
   }

   rmdir($dir);
}

if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
    $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

    $name = explode(".", $filename);
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
        if($mime_type == $type) {
            $okay = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
    if(!$continue) {
        $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
    }

  /* PHP current path */
  $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';  // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in
  $filenoext = basename ($filename, '.zip');  // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in (lowercase)
  $filenoext = basename ($filenoext, '.ZIP');  // absolute path to the directory where zipper.php is in (when uppercase)

  $targetdir = $path . $filenoext; // target directory
  $targetzip = $path . $filename; // target zip file

  /* create directory if not exists', otherwise overwrite */
  /* target directory is same as filename without extension */

  if (is_dir($targetdir))  rmdir_recursive ( $targetdir);


  mkdir($targetdir, 0777);


  /* here it is really happening */

    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $targetzip)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($targetzip);  // open the zip file to extract
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo($targetdir); // place in the directory with same name  
            $zip->close();

            unlink($targetzip);
        }
        $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
    } else {    
        $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
    }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Unzip a zip file to the webserver</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```