# Upload folder that contains subfolders and retain them?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Using a form I am trying to upload a folder that contains files and subfolders that also contains files. I got the folder to upload but when I go to my directory I see all the files in one folder including the subfolders. I want to be able to click upload and click on the folder and submit. Once that is done, if I go to my directory I find the folder with the subfolders also included inside.
Here is my code

html

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
        Folder Name: <input type="text" name="foldername" /><br/>
        Choose Directoryy:  <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory=""><br/>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
</form>
```

php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
        if($_POST['foldername']!="")
        {
                $foldername=$_POST['foldername'];
                if(!is_dir($foldername))
                        mkdir($foldername);
                foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i=>$name)
                {
                        if(strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1)
                        {
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$foldername.'/'.$name);
                        }
                }
                echo "Folder is uploaded successfully ..";
        }
        else
        echo "Folder uploaded Failed!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: "I want to be able to click upload and click on the folder and submit." That's not how browsers or uploads work.

Comment: Http/browsers doesn't support folder uploads like that. When you upload a list of files, it doesn't upload the folder structure too. Next best thing is to zip it all and upload the zip, then unzip on the server

Comment: i am working on a personal form to help me get my job done faster. I dont want to upload all the files at once and go to the folder and start creating new subfolders and dragging the files into it. I just want when i click the upload button the folder and subfolders are retained in my directory. I tried another way where i copy the path and try to create the folders based on the path that's saved for every file but got many errors.

Comment: Maybe you should just use FTP or SFTP to upload your files to the server. As I've already explained, HTTP is not really designed for bulk file transfer and the scenario you've described cannot be implemented exactly as you would like it, whereas those other protocols are designed specifically for file transfer and they understand about folder structures implicitly. It would be much easier to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best Approach For This Is To Upload A ZIP File And Unzip It On The Server As Mentioned In The Comments.

You Can learn more about it here: [Upload Zip File and Extract the Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355653/upload-zip-file-and-extract-the-zip)